# Permutating with repetition and rules between possible values

Tags: python, iteration, constraints, out-of-memory

I am using Python 2.6 and found the function

```
[in] a=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
[in] b=list(itertools.product(*a))
```

Where a is a list of lists and the result is a list with tuples for each posible combination of taking one value from every list in a. I.e.

```
[out]  [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

The problem comes when I start working with a list of 20 lists (the result will be 3**20 different tupples and overflow the memory).
To avoid these I want to apply the constraints I'm applying after creating all the tupples before or during the generation.
This constraints are for example:

- Always two 2s in a row
- 40% of 1s
- Not a 3 after a 1 or 1 after 3
  ...

Can someone help me with an advanced function that could do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One great thing about itertools is that they don't use much memory, they just return an iterator.
You can then do something like:

```
def valid_combination(combination):
    # Do whatever test you want here
    pass

def product_with_validation(validation_func, *element_list):
    for combination in itertools.product(*element_list):
        if validation_func(combination):
            yield combination

all_combinations = list(product_with_combo(product_with_validation, [1,2,3],[1,2,3])
```

product_with_combo does also return an iterator saving a lot of memory.

Ex:

```
import itertools

def valid_combination(combination):
    return len(combination)>0 and combination[0]==2

def product_with_validation(validation_func, *element_list):
    return (combination for combination in itertools.product(*element_list) 
           if valid_combination(combination))
print list(product_with_validation(valid_combination, range(10), range(10)))
```

Result:

```
[(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9)]
```

Ps:

itertools have a function that also does pretty much the same thing as product_with_validation: [ifilter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter), you might wanna use it as it is probably much faster than a custom written one.